# First countability of a disjoint sum

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a family of **compact**, first-countable spaces $K_i$. Let $L$ be the one-point compactification of their disjoint sum. Must $L$ be first-countable?

Note that if we drop the compactness assumption then the answer is *no*: simply take $K=\omega_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, take the $K_i$ to be one-point spaces, and take uncountably many of them.